# Java android show layout after swipe

Tags: java, android

Hi I want to show a layout when I swipe up. I want that would be animated. When I swipe up  below this layout appear another layout. I did this but it not works like I want to. A new layout show after all swipe not when I am swiping .

```
public class RelativeLayoutTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
    private Activity activity;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;// TODO change this runtime based on screen resolution. for 1920x1080 is to small the 100 distance
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    private View view;

    // private MainActivity mMainActivity;

    public RelativeLayoutTouchListener(MainActivity mainActivity, View view) {
        activity = mainActivity;
        this.view = view;
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.e("sdasdas", "dsfdsfdsfsdf");
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;
                final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = MainActivity.relativeLayout1.getLayoutParams();
                if (deltaY < 0) {
                    params.height = (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp);
//                    relativeLayout1.setLayoutParams(params);
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    collapse(relativeLayout1, 400, params.height);
                    MainActivity.listView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
//                    params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    params.height = (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp2);
//                    MainActivity.relativeLayout1.setLayoutParams(params);
                    expand(relativeLayout1, 400, params.height);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    MainActivity.listView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                return false; // no swipe horizontally and no swipe vertically
            }
            // case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void expand(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight) {

        int prevHeight = v.getHeight();

        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevHeight, targetHeight);
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }

    public static void collapse(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight) {
        int prevHeight = v.getHeight();
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevHeight, targetHeight);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a custom Dialog class and when you show it it'll slide up from bottom.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari how I can do this ?

Comment: I've posted it below.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari and when I start A swipe my linearLayout I will see a fragment of another layout ?

Comment: It'll be a Dialog that will come over your current screen with a transparent background. I've edited my answer with the expected output. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari Sorry but no. I want to show you scroll through a longer portion of the next layout something similar action as NavigationView

Comment: You want a new screen on swipe and the old screen to go?

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari I want to new screen go , I want to do this : I have for example relative layout in there is linear layout and when I swipe up linear lauot I will see anothe lineat layout

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dialog class to achieve the animation with ease:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

private Fragment fragment;
private Activity activity;

public CustomDialog(Fragment fragment) {
    super(fragment.getContext(), R.style.DialogTheme);
    this.fragment=fragment;
}

public CustomDialog(Activity activity){
    super(activity, R.style.DialogTheme);
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_photo_upload);

    Window window = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    wlp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    wlp.windowAnimations = R.style.popupWindowDropDownAnimation;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
```

Call this from your Fragment or Activity whenever you want to show it:

```
private CustomDialog mCustomDialog = new CustomDialog(this).show();
```

Call this to hide it:

```
mCustomDialog.dismiss();
```

It'll produce something like [image: this]

Comment: Ok But when I start A swipe my linearLayout I will see a fragment of another layout ?

Comment: It'll be a Dialog that will come over your current screen with a transparent background. I've edited my answer with the expected output. Is that what you want?